# Add a border to a triangle using pure CSS

Tags: css

So, i've created a triangle that points up with a background color of#222 using pure CSS.
I want to add a red 1px border to that triangle, but I have no idea how.

```
.arrow-tip {
    width: 0; height: 0; 
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #222;
}
```

Comment: This is how I would do it, a little different than your approach - using a unicode character for a triangle, then adding a text-shadow for the border.  Small, simple, and clean.  Just something to think about.  See it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/n8Lj4nfv/

Comment: @j08691 haven't you mark this as duplicated?

Comment: @Danko - I did initially, but then I went back and saw that it wasn't really a true dupe and re-opened it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could do something like this is to create another arrow just like it and put it behind the first to fake the border like this:

```css
.arrow-tip {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #222;
    position: relative;
}

.arrow-tip:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -16px;
    left: -17px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-left: 17px solid transparent;
    border-right: 17px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 17px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-tip"></div>
```

You'll have to play with the dimensions until you get it just right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:before` and `:after` sudo selectors to create an arrow shape.

```css
.arrow-tip { 
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.arrow-tip:after,
.arrow-tip:before { 
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow-tip:after { 
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #222;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.arrow-tip:before {
    bottom: -1px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-width: 17px;
    margin-left: -17px
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-tip"></div>
```

JsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tud0czmq/1/